# Why isn't apache satisfied with the first entry in /etc/hosts?

Tags: apache2, hosts

I have `/etc/apache2`

```
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
HostnameLookups Off
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel warn
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf
Include ports.conf
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
AccessFileName .htaccess
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

`/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName richter-local.de
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www/
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

`/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mediawiki.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/mediawiki
  ServerName richter-local.de
</VirtualHost>
```

and `/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1       localhost richter-local.de
127.0.1.1       richter-lenovo-IdeaPad-Z500 richter-local.de
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
192.168.4.102 richter-local.de
192.168.178.62 richter-local.de
141.20.195.79 richter-local.de
192.168.4.101   richter-synology.de
```

`ifconfig` shows

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 20:89:84:86:6d:4f  
          inet Adresse:192.168.4.102  Bcast:192.168.4.255  Maske:255.255.255.0
          inet6-Adresse: fe80::2289:84ff:fe86:6d4f/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Verbindung
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
          RX-Pakete:101131 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
          TX-Pakete:111821 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000 
          RX-Bytes:89237563 (89.2 MB)  TX-Bytes:123567962 (123.5 MB)

lo        Link encap:Lokale Schleife  
          inet Adresse:127.0.0.1  Maske:255.0.0.0
          inet6-Adresse: ::1/128 Gültigkeitsbereich:Maschine
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metrik:1
          RX-Pakete:5882 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
          TX-Pakete:5882 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:0 
          RX-Bytes:1411819 (1.4 MB)  TX-Bytes:1411819 (1.4 MB)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse ea:b9:6b:fe:d3:dd  
          inet Adresse:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Maske:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
          RX-Pakete:0 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
          TX-Pakete:0 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:0 
          RX-Bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX-Bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 68:17:29:77:05:42  
          inet Adresse:192.168.178.62  Bcast:192.168.178.255  Maske:255.255.255.0
          inet6-Adresse: fe80::6a17:29ff:fe77:542/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Verbindung
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
          RX-Pakete:79163 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
          TX-Pakete:109596 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000 
          RX-Bytes:15962887 (15.9 MB)  TX-Bytes:108352352 (108.3 MB)
```

Why does the request of `http://richter-local.de/mediawiki` redirect to `http://richter-synology.de/mediawiki/index.php/Hauptseite`??

This also happens if I comment out the last line `192.168.4.101  richter-synology.de` in `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: Show the content of `/mediawiki/index.php`

Comment: Why do you think it's the hosts file?

Comment: It was my experience that one could move mediawiki as a folder whereever, so I just forgot that I adjusted `LocalSettings.php` before moving it to my NAS and back...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good hint, @Lucio, it's in `/mediawiki/LocalSettings.php`. `$wgServer` has been set to `'http://richter-synology.de'` instead of `'http://richter-local.de'`...